# Cart details getting blank after redirection in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, cart

Here is my config settings:-

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'tbl_ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Here is an ajax function:-

```
        $('#add_to_cart').on('click',function(){
            var rowseat = $('#rowseat').val();
            var movieprice = $('#movie_price').val();
            var moviename = $('#movie_name').val();
            var movieid = $('#movie_id').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url();?>ajax/add_to_cart",
                data: {'movieid':movieid,
                        'moviename':moviename,
                            'movieprice':movieprice,
                            'rowseat':rowseat},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if(data.status==1)
                    {
                        alert("Tickets added to cart");
                        location.href="<?php echo base_url();?>cart";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("Cart addition failed");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

This ajax function calls this php controller function:-

```
include_once('common.php');
class Ajax extends Common {
function __construct() 
{
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('oracle_model');
}
function add_to_cart()
{
    if($this->input->post('movieid'))
    {
        $movieid = $_POST['movieid'];
    }
    if($this->input->post('moviename'))
    {
        $moviename = $_POST['moviename'];
    }
    if($this->input->post('movieprice'))
    {
        $movieprice = $_POST['movieprice'];
    }
    if($this->input->post('rowseat'))
    {
        $rowseat = $_POST['rowseat'];
    }

    $rowseatArr = explode(",",$rowseat);
    foreach($rowseatArr as $rArr)
    {
        $cart['rowseat'] = $rArr;
        $cart['price'] = $movieprice;
        $cart['movie_name'] = $moviename;
        $cart['movie_id'] = $movieid;
        $cartTicket[] = $cart;
    }
    $return = $this->cart_model->validate_add_cart_item($cartTicket);
    if($return == 1)
    {
        $respond['status'] = 1;
        $respond['message'] = 'test';
    }
    else
    {
        $respond['status'] = 0;
        $respond['message'] = 'test';
    }

    echo json_encode($respond);

}
```

Here is my cart_model function which is :

```
function validate_add_cart_item($cartArr)
{
    $cartTicket = 0;
    $totalTicket = count($cartArr);
    foreach($cartArr as $ca)
    {
        $qty = 1; // Assign posted quantity to $cty
        $price = $ca['price'];
        $rowseat= $ca['rowseat'];
        $movie_name= $ca['movie_name'];
        $movie_id = $ca['movie_id'];

        $rowArr = explode("_",$rowseat);
        $name = 'Row'.$rowArr[0].'Seat'.$rowArr[1];

        $id = $movie_id.'-'.$rowArr[0].'-'.$rowArr[1];
        $data = array(
                    'id'      => $id,
                    'qty'     => $qty,
                    'price'   => $price,
                    'name'    => $name,
                    'options' => array('movie'=>$movie_name,'row'=>$rowArr[0],'seat'=>$rowArr[1],
                                       'date'=>date('d-m-Y'),
                                       'showtime_id'=>'',
                                       'showtime'=>'')
        );
        if($this->cart->insert($data))
        {
            $cartTicket++;
        }
    }
    if($totalTicket == $cartTicket)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

As we can see, on success the javascript ajax function redirects to cart controller.

```
include_once('common.php');
class Cart extends Common {
    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('oracle_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        print_r($this->cart->contents());
    }
}
```

This is the common.php controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Common extends CI_Controller {

    protected $_data = array();
    protected $_globalCompanyList = array();
    public $oracleDB = array();
    public $_limit = 10;
    public $_ousername = 'xxxxxx';
    public $_password = 'xxxxxxx';
    public $_localhost = 'xxxxxxx';

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        @session_start();
        $this->load->helper(array('url','form','html'));
        $this->load->library(array('authentication','upload','image_lib','pagination'));
        //$this->lang->load('webpage','dutch');
    }
}
```

After redirecting to the cart controller, the cart is showing blank, even though the data is saved in `tbl_ci_sessions` table.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_ci_sessions (session_id varchar2(40) PRIMARY KEY,
ip_address varchar2(16) NOT NULL,
user_agent varchar2(500) NOT NULL,
last_activity number(10) NOT NULL,
user_data varchar2(4000)
);
```

What am I doing wrong? By the way, I am using oracle 10g express edition with codeigniter.

Comment: what's your server error log shows ?

Comment: I am doing it in local machine. How to check it?

Comment: in linux , often your apache log located in : `/var/log/apache/error.log` , or simply display your error using `ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);` on top of your controller file

Comment: Nothing is showing

Comment: where is this function had been declared ? `$this->cart->contents()` ? and just try to echo some thing there in your controller .

Comment: These are codeigniter inbuilt library

Comment: " and just try to echo some thing there in your controller ." and you meaning by blank , blank white page ? or the page loaded with empty cart ?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" Two things on my mind. First, classes should be named `Like_capital_first.php` and second you are calling controller in conrtoller which is opposite to MVC paradigm. All you have in constructor of Common class you can set in `APPPATH.'.config/autoload.php'` and those parameters in custom config file. Secondly, is session class loaded globaly?

Comment: @Tpojka, session, cart libraries are loaded in autoload.php. The classes haev first letter capital. But I didn't understand, what did you mean by "calling controller in conrtoller"?

Comment: Since it is extending `CI_Controller`, `Common` seems as cotroller itself. That file is not ucfirst-ed. And secondly, all code from that file can be moved to library or autoload as well.

Comment: @Saswat only add relevant code. As well explain what you trying to do and  explain the order of your code and where this error occur. Poor descriptions